# Unity3d - Как задать Vector3 из кода

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне необходимо задавать программно количество позиций, через Vector3;

```
public Vector3[] Positions;
Positions = new Vector3[50];
```

Так же есть `Positions[i] = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f), Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f), 0);` который генерирует позицию элемента, но когда вводим Size в Unity появляются местоположения для них. Мне необходимо задавать всё програмнно.

Но,в интерфейсе Unity почему-то пишется Size ,который нужно указать, но мне нужно их указывать из кода,а не Unity.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не понятно. вы же уже написали `public Vector3[] Positions;
Positions = new Vector3[50]; Positions[i] = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f), Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f), 0);`  так и задается........ Юнити вас не обязывает в интерфейсе все проставлять..... если они мозолят глаз, то можно сделать поля приватными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы не хотите видеть в инспекторе список из `Vector3`, вы можете убрать модификатор доступа `public` у `Vectro3[] Positions`:

```
Vector3[] Positions = new Vector3[50]; // неявно модификатор доступа private
```

Это приведёт к тому, что поля станут приватными (`private`) и из другого класса получить к ним доступ не удастся.

Если же вы хотите или вам нужно оставить список с модификатором доступа `public`, но не хотите видеть список в инспекторе, вы можете использовать `[HideInInspector]`:

```
[HideInInspector]
public string someString = "Here is some text"; // это поле отображено не будет
public float someFloat = 1.5f; // а это поле останется публичным
```

А если хочется отобразить приватные поля для редактирования, можно использовать `[SerializeField]`:

```
[SerializeField]
private float someFloat; // это поле будет отображено в инспекторе
private string someString = "Some text"; // это поле останется приватным
```

Answer (score 1):

Написав этот код:

```
Positions = new Vector3[50];
```

Вы уже задали количество программно. 
Если вы хотите убрать возможность редактировать **Positions** из редактора, уберите модификатор **public** перед `Vector3[] Positions;`

Answer (score 0):

Это стандартный вывод массива в Unity. Редактор первой строкой отображает название массива, второй задается количество элементов через поле `Size`, а дальше попорядку выводятся все элементы один за другим. 
Если вам обязательно надо представлять пользователю `Unity` список без возможности управлять количеством элементов в редакторе, то советую написать свой вариант отображения класса в редакторе. ([Документация `CustomEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html))

Если чувствуете в себе силы, то для красивых списков есть встроенное средство, правда недокументированное, для вывода сортируемых списков. Есть неплохой блог от Валентина Симонова который работает от Unity в России, посмотрите у него [пример](http://va.lent.in/unity-make-your-lists-functional-with-reorderablelist/))